# DataTable.Rows.Find gives "Table doesn't have a primary key" error when table gets too big

Tags: c#

Working with a .NET 3.5 project and I have a DataTable I fill from a MySQL table.  The table contains an "email" column that I need to search on.  I am explicitly setting the primary key, and the following code works fine until I get 422 or more rows in the table.

```
object[] searchfor = new object[] { row["email"] };
DataColumn[] pk = new DataColumn[] { dtAccounts.Columns["email"] };
dtAccounts.PrimaryKey = pk;
match = dtAccounts.Rows.Find(searchfor);
```

I thought maybe there was some bad data in the 422nd record, but have verified that's not the case.  The error I get is "Table doesn't have a primary key", which it obviously does.

Comment: I just tested your code on a table I created manually with 500 entries in it and did not get the error.  Double-check your code out of this scope.

Comment: *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table!* - some SQL guru  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad.  I was filling my `DataTable` via web service, and once I got to 422 rows, the message size was too big and my `DataTable` never got filled.  I just needed to increase the `maxReceivedMessageSize` value in my app.config file.  Error message was less than helpful in this situation!